# Не удается загрузиться с ссд

Tags: windows, bios, ssd

Подключил ссд к ноутбуку и пытаюсь загрузиться, но хоть убей не получается и выходит это ошибка, хотя система видит ссд и приоритете ссд стоит.
Когда вытащил ссд и подключив к нему переходник на USB и подключив его к ноутбуку по разъему, то она удалось зайти в виндовс. Ребята помогите пожалуйста уже день вожусь (

Не нашел никакого ahci. ВОПРОС СТОИТ. ПОЖАЛУЙСТА ПОМОГИТЕ С НИМ )

[image: ошибка]

[image: система видит ссд]

[image: в приоритете стоит ссд]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: advanced]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[![введите сюда описание изображения][7]][7]
```

Comment: Старый ноутбук Asus Pentium inside  точно не знаю модель

Comment: Где-то в настройках SATA проверьте чтобы режим стоял `AHCI`, типа такого https://o.dns-shop.ru/original/st4/54e6c1fb1cd203b8ffe097082d587bef/37643910c95cb2f7f81ce841bdbd3691d88947c0707248a2eb8862b0cede289f.png

Comment: Не помогло. Не нашел это

Comment: "не помогло" это когда сделал, что предложили, и все равно не работает. А если не нашел, то не знаешь, помогло или нет.

Comment: Ну вот нашли же, меняйте этот SATA Operation Mode на что-то другое (Enhanced или что там в вашем биосе)

Comment: Не задаётся все таки. Там два пункта compatible и enhanced но не работает